# nothing showed up after click a link(from database) in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have a database called `simple_stall` with table `order_detail` which have 4 columns `ID` `Name` `Ordered_Item` `Quantity`...currently after user submit their order, they'll be redirected to a page called `order_detail.php`...this page will show all ordered item in table with header `ID` `Name` `Ordered_Item` `Quantity`

now, when user click on someone's name from the table, i want to redirect user to a new page called `view_more.php` which will show the item ordered by the user however, nothing showed in the page.

This is my code:
`index.php`

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="insert_data.php" method="POST">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="Order" placeholder="Order">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="Quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Send Order</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

`insert_data.php`

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    include_once 'dbh.php';

    // Escape user inputs for security
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['Name']);
    $order = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['Order']);
    $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['Quantity']);

    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO order_detail (Name, Ordered_Item, Quantity) VALUES ('$name', '$order', '$quantity')";

    if(mysqli_query($connection, $sql))
        header("Location: ./order_detail.php?status=ordered");
    else
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($connection);


    // close connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
} 
else
{
    header("Location: ./index.php?status=failed");
    exit();
}
```

`order_detail.php`

```
<body>
 <table>
 <tr>
  <th width="30px">No</th> 
  <th width="30%">Name</th> 
  <th width="30%">Ordered Item</th>
  <th width="50px">Quantity</th>
 </tr>

<?php

include_once 'dbh.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM order_detail"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

echo "<table border = 1px>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   
    $name = $row['Name'];
    //Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo  "<tr><td style = 'width:30px;'>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>
               <td style = 'width:30%;'>" . "<a href='view_more.php?id=$name'>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>
               <td style = 'width:30%;'>" . $row['Ordered_Item'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['Quantity'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

mysqli_close($connection); //Make sure to close out the database connection

?>
```

`view_more.php`

```
if (isset($_POST['Name']))
{
    include_once 'dbh.php';

    $name = $row['Name'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM order_detail WHERE Name = $name";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    echo "<table border = 1px>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {   
        //Creates a loop to loop through results
        echo  "<tr><td style = 'width:30px;'>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>
                   <td style = 'width:30%;'>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>
                   <td style = 'width:30%;'>" . $row['Ordered_Item'] . "</td>
                   <td>" . $row['Quantity'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
    }

    echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

    mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not show,

because on `view_more.php` you have  `if (isset($_POST['Name']))` which will never be true since you are not using `$_POST` on `view_more.php`, you are using `<td style = 'width:30%;'>" . "<a href='view_more.php?id=$name'>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>` you are using normal link so replace it with this code

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    include_once 'dbh.php';

    $name = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM order_detail WHERE Name = '$name'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    echo "<table border = 1px>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {   
        //Creates a loop to loop through results
        echo  "<tr><td style = 'width:30px;'>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>
                   <td style = 'width:30%;'>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>
                   <td style = 'width:30%;'>" . $row['Ordered_Item'] . "</td>
                   <td>" . $row['Quantity'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
    }

    echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

    mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

and you should be good to go, however, I highly recommend you to use proper php framework.

Comment: hey, thanks..but now it showed 
`Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple_stall\view_more.php on line 14`
Any reason why?
Also, what do you mean by php framework? like the `method=post` ?

Comment: back to blank page

Comment: oh wait, found wrong code in `order_detail.php` 
it workss! thanks~

Answer (score 0):

When generating the link to the `view_more.php` page, you're are injecting a GET param named `id`:

```
<a href='view_more.php?id=$name'>
```

And on the `view_more.php` page, you are testing for a POST param called `name`:

```
if (isset($_POST['Name']))
```

fix this to

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
```

By the way, your code is really, really ugly. there are a tons of things done wrong :

- unescaped params in SQL query : you are exposed to [SQL injections](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) which is a severe security breach.
- coupled PHP and HTML scripts : take a look at [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and [MVC Design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)